# android:Resolved:Unable to parse Currency data text obtained from UTF-8 data

Tags: android, xml, utf-8, currency

Hi
I am trying to fetch this xml response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<desc c="¥99"/>
```

but on my Android each time I get **Â¥99** ,after parsing the xml, instead of correct data(i.e.**¥99**).Is there any way to parse this Currency data correctly.Please correct me if I am missing something.
EDIT:Here is the code that is used to get xml

```
docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder ();
    InputSource is = new InputSource ();
    is.setEncoding ("UTF-8");
    Document doc = null;

        is.setCharacterStream (new StringReader (xmlStr));
        doc = docBuilder.parse (is);

    if (doc != null)
    {
            doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
            NodeList detail = doc.getElementsByTagName ("desc");
            String c = detail.item (0).getAttributes ().getNamedItem ("c").getNodeValue ();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
Thanks for your support I recognized the problem ,the method in which I was getting response from server had below code

```
String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString (response.getEntity ());
```

where `response.getEntity ().getContentEncoding () returned null so I changed it to

```
String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString (response.getEntity (),"UTF-8");
```

where "UTF-8" is default charset.

Thanks StackOverFlow!

Comment: Glad you found it. I would have said the issue is where you're reading in the string `xmlStr`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you parse the XML. For instance, one of the overloaded `Xml#parse()` methods accepts an `Xml.Encoding` argument that you can use to specify that the source is UTF-8.

Other parsing methods likely have an option to set the encoding, as well. Just check the docs.

Of course, it's entirely possible that the server doesn't generate correct UTF-8, even though it's declared as such in the XML file.

Comment: I have posted the code (see edited section above) .I also did tried is.setEncoding ("UTF-8"). but it too is of no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we had the code where you are reading the XML stream.
I would assume that you need to ensure you're reading the stream in the correct encoding (as the stream reader may not take the XML declaration's encoding into account.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like well-formed XML. There is no attribute name, only the `c` element. That seems reason enough not to get correct results...

Answer (score 0):

OK, with the example code, I'd guess it's the `setCharacterStream()` that fouls things up. Without having tested it myself, the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) say that encodings are used only by byte streams, so use `setByteStream()` instead, or, better use the [byte stream constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#InputSource%28java.io.InputStream%29) of `InputSource`.